# How to manage array of states effectively?

Tags: react.js, user-interface, state

I have a working code to have 2 search bars with dropdown suggestions, selectable by both mouse and arrow keys in TypeScript and Fresh/Preact. In there I have to explicitly declare individual hooks for different lists:

```
const list1 = ['rabbits', 'raccoons', 'reindeer', 'red pandas', 'rhinoceroses', 'river otters', 'rattlesnakes', 'roosters'] as const 
const list2 = ['jacaranda', 'jacarta', 'jack-o-lantern orange', 'jackpot', 'jade', 'jade green', 'jade rosin', 'jaffa'];
export default function SearchBar() {
  const [resultList1, setResultList1] = useState<null | (typeof list1[number])[]>(null);
  const [cursor1, setCursor1] = useState<Cursor>(0); 
  const [selectedItem1, setSelectedItem1] = useState<null | typeof list1[number]>(null); // State to track selected item for list 1
  
  const [resultList2, setResultList2] = useState<null | (typeof list2[number])[]>(null);
  const [cursor2, setCursor2] = useState<null | number>(0); // State to track selected item for list 2
  const [selectedItem2, setSelectedItem2] = useState<null | typeof list2[number]>(null); // State to track selected item for list 2
  
  /** activeList is used to determine whether the suggestion list should be popup or not */
  const [activeList, setActiveList] = useState<null | '1' | '2'>(null); // State to track active list
```

And explicitly return individual divs for different lists.

```html
<div 
  id='search-div-1' 
  className="search-bar-container"
  >
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder={'Search list 1'}
    onInput={(e) => {
      setResultList1(list1.filter(item => item.includes((e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value)));
    }}
    onFocus={() => setActiveList('1')}
    onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
    />
  <br />
  {resultList1 && activeList === '1' ? SuggestedList() : null}
  Cursor: {cursor1}<br />
  Selected item: <span id="Item 1">{selectedItem1}</span><br />
</div>
<div 
  id='search-div-2' 
  className="search-bar-container"
  >
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder={'Search list 2'}
    onInput={(e) => {
      setResultList2(list2.filter(item => item.includes((e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement).value)));
    }}
    onFocus={() => setActiveList('2')}
    onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
    />
  <br />
  {resultList2 && activeList === '2' ? SuggestedList() : null}
```

[Full code here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78231149/1).

I wonder if this is a good approach or not. My next step for this is to have the suggested lists disappear when they are unfocused by integrating it with [Detect click outside multiple components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78231986/3416774).

Comment: The question is related to the following meta post: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor that component into a main component, and each list will have its own component. Then you can reuse the list component multiple times:

```
export default function SearchBarSplit() {
  /** Active list is used to determine whether the search list should be popup or not */
  const [activeList, setActiveList] = useState<ActiveList>(null); 
  return (
<>
  <SearchDiv listName="1" list={list1} activeList={activeList} setActiveList={setActiveList} />
  <SearchDiv listName="2" list={list2} activeList={activeList} setActiveList={setActiveList} />
  Active list: <strong>{activeList}</strong>
</>
  );
}
function SearchDiv({listName, list, activeList, setActiveList}: {listName: '1' | '2', list: List, activeList: ActiveList, setActiveList: StateUpdater<ActiveList>}){
  const [searchList, setSearchList] = useState<null | SearchList>(null);
  const [cursor, setCursor] = useState<Cursor>(0); 
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<null | SelectedItem>(null); 
...
```

[Full code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78231149/3416774).

Head over to [Managing State – React](https://react.dev/learn/managing-state) to learn more many ways to manage states.